# REST vs SOAP regarding distribute vs p-to-p point

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, distributed-computing

There is lot of argument around SOAP vs REST.

I am here only focus on the point of:

SOAP was designed for a distributed computing environment(loose coupling for integrating diverse system).

Where as REST was designed for a point to point environment.

I am not quite get the point here: does that mean REST can't be used in distributed computing environment?
and SOAP can't be used for point to point?

Can someone give me a deep explanation around this? Because, I did not see this two propose conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view - there is no real conflict, it’s much rather an ideology.

REST is simple, based on HTTP and leverages all the features from the underlying protocol in order to allow as much as possible and be as flexible as possible. If you write ASP.NET applications, you can see nicely that there is almost no difference between REST applicatons (ASP.NET Web API) and tradditional Websites (ASP.NET MVC) - in fact I believe that the difference disappeard almost totally again in the lastest version (ASP.NET vNext).

SOAP on the other hand offers much more within the protocol and doesn’t use the features of the underlying HTTP soo extensively. This way SOAP is also seend as more complex than REST or more sohpisticated. This is also the reason why SOAP is (or maybe used to be) more often used in enterprise applications, while REST is rather handled by the web and startup world where you want to stay flexible.

But both protocols can be used in any way you want - client/server, p2p - there is no restriction from this side